# Uninitialized Constant for Rails worker (it's included in my autoload paths)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some of my Rails workers in a subdirectory called "enum", for example:

```
/var/www/myapp/app/workers/
/var/www/myapp/app/workers/enum
```

However, the workers inside of the `enum` directory doesn't seem to be loading with the application. If I try to call a worker that resides in there, it just gives me the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CurrentWorkerWorker::MyCustomWorker
```

I should also note that `current_worker.rb` resides within the root `workers` folder, whereas `my_custom_worker.rb` resides in `workers/enum`.

When I run `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths`, I noticed that the `workers` and the `workers/enum` folder are both in the list (I just added the `workers/enum` folder as part of troubleshooting), but it's still not working.

Any thoughts as to why this may not be loading? Rails seems to only be processing the workers that are within the root `workers` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add subdirectories to the existing autoload paths you can do the following inside `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/workers/**')
```

Comment: I've done that but it's still giving me the same error. I'm not quite sure why it stopped working.